# How can I stop getting Twitter notifications about things that have nothing to do with me?

Tags: twitter, notifications

I have been getting notifications (i.e. the Notifications link on the top with the little bell next to it has a number) when someone that I follow retweets a photo from someone else.  This interaction has nothing to do with me and I do not want to be notified about it as if it's something important.

How can I say that I only want notifications that are "for me"?  (i.e. someone replied to or liked my tweet, I received a direct message, etc.)

Comment: Cf. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121206/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-this-person-follows-tweets