# How Can I Get Rid of the "This Person" Follows Tweets?

Tags: twitter, tweet, follow, twitterfeed

My Twitter feed gets filled with random tweets about "this or that person follows" and I get random tweets that I don't want. I'd rather have my feed filled with people I follow and not have to scroll past all these random, unwanted tweets. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Go to setting > go to muted words.

Add 'suggest_activity_tweet' and 'suggest_recycled_tweet_inline' as muted words.